# I want to make a list appear when I click on a square, How to do that in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 div block: the first one contains three div square and the other one a list. Aside every square, there is a list content. I want to make a list appear when I click on a square, How to do that in javascript? P.S: I don't want the all list appear, but the one corresponding to his square. For example, when I click on the first square, I want the home appear,  the second square show the about and the last one for the contact.

```
<div class="ss">
    <div class="s">
    </div>
                    
    <div class="s">
    </div>
                    
    <div class="s">
    </div>
                    
</div>
                
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>

        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You ask a javascript question and show html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?
Added CSS so as display no list initially. Then had modified the html to include `id` and then used a js function.

```
<style>
    .list {display: none;}
</style>

<div class="ss">
    <div class="s" onclick = "Show('home')">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="s" onclick = "Show('about')">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="s" onclick = "Show('contact')">DIV 3</div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="list" id = "home">Home</li>
        <li class="list" id = "about">About</li>
        <li class="list" id = "contact">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>

    function Show(element) {

        var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            list[i].style.display = "none";

       document.getElementById(element).style.display = "list-item";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the list by using

```
display:none;
```

and add an eventlistner to the div that you want the user to click on to view the list and on click change the display of the list to block like this

```
document.querySelector(".<your div's classname>").addEventListner("click",function(){
    document.querySelector(".list").style.display="block";
});
```

Comment: I don't want the all list appear, but the one corresponding to his square. For example, when I click on the first square, I want the home appear,  the second square show the about and the last home for the contact.

Comment: @codeboi until OP show some code, dont be pressured to answer his/her non-debug-gable questions in future

Comment: yeah but i think i get what hes trying to do now

Comment: Its a dead end @codeboi. Cant debug whats not there. You'll get strung along. There is no solution here because there is no problem stated. It just goes and on and on

Comment: its not a matter of debugging. He dosent know where to start .He just stated what he wanted to do

Comment: Here my javascript code: `var mesDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("ss").getElementsByClassName("s");
     
     mesDiv.addEventListener("click", montrer);
     
     
     var maListe = document.getElementsByClassName("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
     
     var liste = "";
     for(var i=0; i<maListe.length; i++){
      liste+=maListe[i];
     }
     
     function montrer(){
      liste.style.display = "block"; 
     }`